# Youtube Video Embed Not Functional On iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, ios, youtube

I'm trying to use Youtube's new video embed code, which detects via the iframe if the browser supports flash or not and delivers the appropriate content.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/i2b8pEuj0U8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But, after checking on the iPhone, it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I could go about making a youtube video functional on the iPhone?

Comment: Could you post some more of your code? I recently had to update my code to this for it to work on iOS 6.0. Also, note, this sometimes doesn't work in the simulator.

Comment: Hi bbodayle, thanks for replying. 

I'm running this in isolation, over at www.dentasignclients.com/youtube.html, to make sure there's nothing interfering on the main site.

The only thing other than the youtube code is an <html> tag.

What changes did you make to get it to work on IOS6?

Comment: Ohp, I think I figured out the problem. I'm in China right now, and realized I don't have a VPN on the iphone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I didn't have a VPN on the iphone, and since I'm in China, it was blocked by the great firewall :P